# Using http client - how to get Java to automatically download intermediate SSL certificates

Tags: java, scala, https

I'm setting up a HTTPS connection to a remote server that I have no control over.  The server has an SSL certificate that is generated by a trusted CA but doesn't include the intermediate certificates in their SSL handshake.

Eg.
trusted CA cert -> intermediate cert (not provided) -> server cert (provided)

Typically a server would provide the server cert and intermediate certs.  Without the intermediate cert my HTTP client doesn't recognize the SSL cert and the SSL connection fails.

I'm trying to connect using Apache HTTP client 4.5:

```scala
  val httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .useSystemProperties()
```

I can get things working if I download the certificates, set them up in a keystore and attach it to the connection:

```scala
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
  val certPem = new PEMParser(new PemReader(new FileReader("trust-chain.crt")))
  val certHolder = certPem.readObject().asInstanceOf[X509CertificateHolder]
  val cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
    .setProvider("BC")
    .getCertificate(certHolder)
  val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType)
  keyStore.load(null)
  keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert-alias", cert)

  val sslContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create()
    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray)
    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, null)

  val httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .useSystemProperties()
    .setSSLContext(sslContextBuilder.build())
```

But this is going to break as soon as the certificates expire.  I could also enable trusting self signed certificates but that has pretty big security implications and I don't want to go that way:

```scala
  val sslContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create()
    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray)
    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy)
```

Is there any way to set up Apache HTTP Client (or another JVM HTTPS/SSL library) to automatically download the intermediate certificates if the server does not provide them (similar to most web browsers)?

Comment: Download them from where?

Comment: @JamesKPolk that is a good question - I'm not entirely sure, likely the trusted CA - I know the ssllabs ssltest (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) was able to pick them up from somewhere and noted "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B."  I was also able to download them via another site that pulled the entire certificate chain into the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- .... -----END CERTIFICATE----- format so I think it is a solvable problem.

Comment: Some CAs make some of their intermediate roots available somewhere on their site. It is not a reliable or standard way to obtain the intermediate certs.  You don't need to download the intermediate certs to know they are missing. I doubt sslabs downloaded them.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm guessing (hoping) there must be some standard way as I was able to go to the same server with my web browser and the web browser was able to pull down the intermediate certificates and validate the site, I'm just hoping there is an automated way to do the same in the JVM

Comment: BTW there was no need to use BouncyCastle here; [standard CertificateFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) can read PEM or DER cert (from a file or stream), in only two or even one line of code, since almost the beginning of Java

Answer (score 4):

I found [an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162592/why-do-i-need-to-add-intermediate-ca-certificates-to-jvms-cacerts-file#answer-168061) to this.

Using the Oracle JRE you can enable automatic downloading of intermediate certificates with the Java system property `-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true`

For this to work the server's certificate must provide the URI to the intermediate certificate (the certificate's issuer).