# CFHTTP unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: coldfusion, ssl-certificate, cfhttp

I'm looking to scrape data off a website, other https sites work and this was working last week but now fails

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.cliftoncameras.co.uk/all-brands-and-types-of-used-cameras/"></cfhttp>
```

If I run a dump of cfhttp

> Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

I have tried running with the latest JRE version 12 - **no change**

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html

Reverted back to CF original JRE, downloaded the target SSL certificate and installed it using the keytool - **no change**

> c:\ColdFusion2018\jre\bin\keytool -import -keystore cacerts -alias
>   cliftoncameras -file
>   c:\ColdFusion2018\jre\lib\security\cliftoncameras.cer

I changed the websocket in the CFAdmin to proxy - **no change**

I did restart the CF Application Server each time.

What else can I do?

Comment: When you updated the JRE did you import the certificate into the correct keystore file? It would no longer be the default location that came with ColdFusion as shown in your example.

Comment: I tried it with both, one at a time depending on which one was in use. thanks

Comment: Assuming you have access to the jvm.config settings, make a backup of that file. Then modify it to enable debugging. i..e. Add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and restart CF. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: `this was working last week`  What changed in between last week and this week.. updates, code changes, ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my development platform I added

```
-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true
```

To the java.args in the file in ColdFusion2018\cfusion\bin\jvm.config

Then restarted the CF Application Server, and now my CFHTTP call is successful.

Thanks to @agreax for this solution

Thanks to @sevroberts who's answer was probably the correct one, even though I couldn't get it to work. The production host installed the SSL certificate to the keystore and successfully resolved it this way. They said:

> If you use FireFox browser and click on the lock icon when browsing the URL you are wanting to have the cfhttp request access you can then get the more info and click the View Certificate option. 
>   You will need to download the PEM (cert) not the Chain. Once downloaded, you need to run the keytool in order to import it to the keystore.
>
> If you are using the default JRE within your JVM for ColdFusion you will need to install a JDK to your development machine.
>   You can see the details and steps we have listed on our wiki regarding the commands from the command prompt to import the SSL into the store.
>   https://wiki.hostek.com/ColdFusion_Tips_%26_Tricks#Fixing_cfhttp_Connection_Failures_with_Keytool

Thanks to @alexbaban his workaround, whilst it worked, it was a solution I could not implement due to requiring the use of the tag cfexecute.

Comment: So the host was able to resolve it by installing the certs?

Comment: That's what they said, however I had another CFHTTP issue with another vendor - and after I installed their SSL certificate to the keystore on DEV it was OK! It wasn't even an issue on production. Inconsistent problems are such a headache

Comment: Edit - Ugh.... inconsistent results are such a pain. Are you using the same configuration as Prod? Differences in CF or JVM might explain it.

Answer (score 3):

I have also seen this `java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException` error before from Java and Coldfusion on sites that load ok in a regular browser, but which still error from cfhttp even after adding the certificate to the CF keystore and restarting.

This happens when the target site server certificate configuration has a trust chain issue - when one or more trust chain paths requires the browser to perform an "extra download" of a certificate. This can be because of a missing intermediate certificate in a single trust chain path, or because there are multiple branches in the trust chain with different fingerprints and one or more certificates from one or more of those branches is not being served.

If you run the target site through an SSL Analyzer like ssllabs.com - eg 
https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html?d=www.cliftoncameras.co.uk&hideResults=on - you'll see that their intermediate certificate `Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2` is not being served by their server, which forces the client to do an "extra download" - which won't be a problem for most proper browsers, but the Java client used by cfhttp needs the server to provide pretty much every intermediate and root cert directly. It used to be the same for most mobile OSs up until a few years ago.

So the ideal solution is to contact cliftoncameras and have their server admin install the correct Starfield Intermediate certificate so that it is served correctly.

A possible workaround on your side is to install the `Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2` intermediate certificate in your CF keystore.

Comment: Thank you, I don't really have any say over what cliftoncameras do, so I will try adding the intermediate certificate.

Comment: I installed many of the Starfield certificates, including the ones from the SSL analyzer - nothing made a difference.

Comment: Daniel Cook - Interestingly the cfhttp call works on trycf.com, but only with Lucee 5.  Wasn't able to figure out why.  I tried installing the "Starfield Secure..." cert and cliftoncameras cert, but still no joy.  Undoubtedly I missed something, but not sure what ... Anyway, [this thread mentioned a JVM arg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249930/8895292) which did the trick for me: `-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true`. Steps 1) make backup of jvm.config file (**don't forget to do this**) 2) Add the -Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true argument 3) restart CF server

Comment: Agreax that did it! Many Thanks, I just have to see if I can convince the host to make the change on the live server!

Comment: @Agreax if you'd like to write a small answer up I'll give it credit.

Comment: @DanielCook - Glad to hear it! Thanks, but since you put a lot of work into this, feel free to write up an answer. Side note, I'd love to know why it works on trycf.com, in case there's another option that might work :-)

Comment: The production host added the SSL certificates to the keystore, and it's now working on production too. Have asked them for more information about what SSL certificate they added

Comment: Good spot on the enableAIAcaIssuers arg in that other post - although the rest of the post seems to be confirming mine ;-)  I suspect that the reason it worked on Lucee 5 on trycf.com will just be because they have that Starfield cert already installed or are using different JVM args. On my Lucee 5 box I get the PKIX path building error if I don't install any extra certs. On my Adobe CF box I got the PKIX error but installing both certs and restarting CF was enough for me. I'm not sure why that would work for me and not you - are you sure you were downloading the intermediate and not the root?

Answer (score 1):

If you can not get the keystore thing working maybe you'll want to try this.

Create a dedicated command line executable (.exe) which will read the web page and save the source to a text file. You can then use ColdFusion to read the file and work with the data.

Here is the ColdFusion code:

```js
<cfscript>

    _execPath = "c:/bin/clifton.exe";
    _filePath = "c:/bin/clifton.txt";

    // run your command-line app (clifton.exe)
    cfexecute(name="#_execPath#");  

    // wait for the file
    do {
        sleep(100);
    } while ( not fileExists(_filePath) ) 

    // wait for write to finish
    do {
        sleep(100);
        _fileInfo = getFileInfo(_filePath);
        writeOutput(" ## ");
        cfflush();
    } while ( _fileInfo.size eq 0 || dateDiff("s", _fileInfo.lastmodified, now()) lte 3 )

    writeOutput("<hr />")

    _result = fileRead(_filePath);
    writeDump(_result);

</cfscript>
```

As you can see it depends on `clifton.exe` and reads `clifton.txt` (clifton.txt is the result of executing clifton.exe).

---

**How to make `clifton.exe`**

You will use the Dart SDK and the `dart2native` tool to create the executable on your development computer. You can deploy the executable on your production server as a standalone (You don't need the Dart SDK installed on production).

- Create a `bin` folder on your C drive.
- From https://ssl-ccp.secureserver.net/repository/?origin=CALLISTO download the certificate `sfig2.crt.pem (PEM)` and save it inside `c:\bin`.
- Inside `c:\bin` create a text file `clifton.dart` with the following code:

```dart
// clifton.dart

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  //
  const String _certFilePath = 'c:/bin/sfig2.crt.pem';
  const String _responseFilePath = 'c:/bin/clifton.txt';
  const String _uri =
      'https://www.cliftoncameras.co.uk/all-brands-and-types-of-used-cameras/';

  final File _file = new File(_responseFilePath);
  final IOSink _sink = _file.openWrite();

  final SecurityContext _context = new SecurityContext();
  _context.setTrustedCertificates(_certFilePath);

  final HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(context: _context);
  saveSourceToFile(_client, _uri, _sink);
  _client.close();
  //
}

// get web page source then write it to file
void saveSourceToFile(HttpClient _client, String _uri, IOSink _sink) {
  //
  _client
      .getUrl(Uri.parse(_uri))
      .then((req) => req.close())
      .then((res) => res.transform(Utf8Decoder()).listen((data) {
            // as data is received write to file
            _sink.write(data);
          }, onDone: () {
            _sink.close();
          }));
  //
}
```

- Download and install the Dart SDK from https://dart.dev/
- Open a terminal window and test the installation of Dart with `dart --version` (you should be able to run dart from any folder, if needed add dart to your PATH)
- In a terminal window, change directory to `c:\bin` with `cd c:\bin`
- Next, run `dart2native clifton.dart -o clifton.exe`
- If compilation goes well you should have inside `c:\bin` the three files: `clifton.dart`, `clifton.exe` and the certificate `sfig2.crt.pem`.
- If you wish you can test run `clifton.exe` in the terminal window, which should create the `clifton.txt` file.
- Test the ColdFusion page which calls `clifton.exe`, waits for `clifton.txt` then outputs the content.

If you deploy in production you need both files `clifton.exe` and `sfig2.crt.pem` (the certificate).

**Good luck!**

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the detailed suggestion. I think it's time I try contacting the retailer about the issue before engaging in such a considerable work around.

Comment: You're welcome. It's tested, even if you need to install Dart you can have it all done in less than half an hour.

Comment: Ok well then I'm almost sold! I would need to extract several URLs, so an array of urls / export files, and a loop to create them. I will consider a modification to the code you've provided.

Comment: Exactly. Let me know if you get stuck. You can call `saveSourceToFile(_client, _uri, _sink);` multiple times. You can keep the same `_client` just pass different `_uri` and `_sink`. You might need to use recursion due to async nature of each call.

Comment: Whilst it works! thanks. I realise cfexecute doesn't run, and a quick internet search reminds me why. The shared production host provider will not want to enable it either. https://wiki.hostek.com/ColdFusion_FAQs#Can_I_use_CFExecute.3F